# \includegraphics restriction to the number of calls

Tags: graphics

Is there any restriction about `\includegraphics` usage? This question arise from a LaTeX document where the number of `\includegraphics` has an uncommon result. When exceeded a limit number of includes at a particular section, the following includes aren't displayed (no error).

Comment: No, there shouldn't be a problem usually. Let me try it on my texmaker and get back to you.

Comment: I tried in a section 8 images. They got displayed.

Comment: In my case, I have a total of 38 images in separated includes. At the same chapter, one section with 16 figures and another section with 13 figures. From the second section since the second image, the other figures aren't displayed.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: You're probably getting the `Too many unprocessed floats` error message. See the duplicate question I linked to.

Comment: You are right, it's the same issue. Using \clearpage at beginning of every doc solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[There are several integer-valued registers (called counters in TeX jargon) that limit the number of floats on a page: the number at the top, the number at the bottom, and the total. In addition, there are limits on the fraction of a page that can be occupied by floats — again, at the top and bottom separately, as well as the page as a whole.
...
 If the [p] option has been provided to individual figures and tables, they may be pushed together onto a “float page” that has no text. But even here, the defaults are stingy about the amount of space taken up.](http://mintaka.sdsu.edu/GF/bibliog/latex/floats.html)

Based on this statement, occured to me, if clustering subfigures of a figure whose occupy the "float page" limits, would solve the problem. It worked fine!

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
   \begin{subfigure}[b]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth] {./images/0} 
      \label{aload0}
      \caption{} 
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth] {./images/1} 
      \label{aload1}
      \caption{} 
  \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
```

...

Same structure repeated to the other figures.

Comment: If this solved your problem, then the question seems to be completely unrelated. Yes, you would not have received an error, but you would have been able to see all the images. Moreover, there's no need to include them in sub-figures if the only intent is to just *show* them. You can include a number of `\includegraphics` in the same float (`figure` environment), and that would be fine.